# Xul's listitem command attribute does not work?

Tags: javascript, command, action, xul

Xul's listitem [command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/listitem#a-command) attribute does not work?

I've made this sample, and it's just not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <commandset>
        <command id="cmd_dump" oncommand="dump('ok');" />
    </commandset>

    <vbox style="background:#FFFFFF;" flex="1">
        <spacer flex="1" />
        <hbox pack="center">

            <listbox flex="1">
                <listitem label="Test1" command="cmd_dump" />
                <listitem label="Test2" command="cmd_dump" />
            </listbox>

        </hbox>
        <spacer flex="1" />
    </vbox>

</window>
```

How to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it work"? It's not clear what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: @Neil I'm either not sure how this command was suppose to be fired, but for what I need I added an "enter" key listener and a mouseclick listener. I'm using the list as a list of options that the user will use to enter in a new submenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally listboxes are designed to provide a single or multiple selection, rather than a list of actions. As far as I can tell from your question, you're providing some sort of customisation UI, in which case you have a number of options:

1. Create a multiple selection listbox. The user selects the items they want. This can be cumbersome because they need to remember to hold down the Ctrl key to toggle the selection of a particular item.
2. Create a multiple checkbox listbox. The user ticks the items they want.
3. Provide two listboxes and buttons labelled (e.g.) "Add →" and "← Remove". This also allows the option of "Move Up" and "Move Down" to allow the user to reorder the chosen items.

Comment: actually, I want something like a list of buttons, that the user can fire the action using a mouse click or enter key. I did this using key and mouse listeners, but would be easiest if it could happens simply by setting the command attribute.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining the desired UI so all I can think of is that you put a bunch of buttons inside a richlistbox.

Comment: @Neil what I did is in my question sample. Now I would like that to execute the command (specified in `command` attribute) without need to add key and mouse listeners to it.

Comment: @Neil by the way, use @Tom Brito in the beggining of the comment, so it will show up in my summary.. ;)

Comment: @Tom Brito what I mean is that I don't understand why the user would want to interact with a list in such a way. I'd need some sort of "big picture" overview so that I can see what's going on.

Comment: @Neil for example, a tablet's app list that can be entered with a touch screen (treated as mouse click) or with a enter key press from a external keyboard (treated by a keyboard event). I could remove both events if the list's command attribute handled it.

Comment: @Tom Brito Sorry, I still can't improve on a richlistbox of buttons. By the way, only actual buttons respond to enter key presses. Other button-like widgets only respond to the space key.

Comment: @Neil not possible then. Ok, I can try make something like a list using a panel with buttons and some CSS..

Answer (score 2):

Tom - I come to the same conclusion as yours, having tried in a different way to make a command work, and quickly checked on the Internet (I even found one of your posts on a forum from the beginning of the month).

However, have you tried it with an old version of Firefox (or an old version of the XULRunner engine)?
Maybe you can change slightly want you want your screen to be, like using a command when going out of it, so that you can avoid this problem?

It may be worth asking your question on this channel : #xul on irc.mozilla.org.
They may end up telling you it's a bug.

Comment: This channel looks a good thing, unfortunately the only guy there (krl) didn't answered me. Thought he was away, but I stay connected all day long yestarday. About try an old version of FF: I'm not using FF, just xulrunner. I could try, but even if it work, I need my current version (1.9.2.13). Anyway, as answared to Manu, I found a workaround, I just was trying to see if it was a bug or a mistake of mine, so I can open a bug report. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't work for me either. But making `type = checkbox` does fire the `command`. You can get rid of the checkbox using absolute positioning and negative margins but thats an ugly hack.

A better way would be to listen for the `click` event of the `<listitem>` in Javascript.

As Cedric said, it might be a bug although the example at [controllers - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/controllers) works.

Comment: Actually, I when I needed it I added the mouse and keyboard events needed, but as you just said, it was an ugly solution. I just wanted to know that's really a bug, not some bad use of mine, so I can open a bug report. About the controllers example, I didn't understand well what was supposed to fire the delete event.. anyway..

Comment: Pressing the delete button fires "cmd_delete". But only the commands given in http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/places/content/controller.js are allowed. Also, I opened the XUL file as file:// and that didn't give me access to appendController (my bad!) but other than that, the example works.